# How to query the V shaped data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
TxnID    RunningAmount    MemberID
==================================
1        80000            20
2        90000            20
3        70000            20  //<==== Falls but previously never below 100k, hence ignore
4        90000            20
5        110000           20  
6        60000            20  //<==== Falls below 100k, hence we want ID 8
7        80000            20
8        120000           20
9        85000            28
...
....
```

How to construct the query such that it group by members, get the first transactionID that formed the "V" shape. Even a pseudocode is fine, I can't share my attempt because I am totally clueless about how to do it.

**UPDATES:**

Sorry for the lack of explanations on the conditions. The base amount we looking is 100k. **ID is random, definitely we need to have rownumber**

1. We ignore all transactions before `ID = 5` because their `runningAmount` is never exceeded 100k.
2. Now when `ID=5`, exceeded 100k, we check if transactions after `ID=5` if there is a down trend in `runningAmount` that falls below 100k.
3. Immediately we see `ID=6` falls below 100k, so we want to find the first transaction that exceed 100k again(if there is).

From the data sample above, the expected result is only one record, which is `ID=8`.

For every member, there will only be either one or zero record found based on the conditions I've mentioned

Comment: It is not clear, at least not to me, what you are actually trying to achieve. Can you provide the expected result for the sample data posted? Also, can you elaborate on the logic of producing the result?

Comment: so you want to find three successive records with `RunningAmount` above 100k, below 100k, above 100k, and you want the id of the last?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos: From the above data sample, I only want the record with `ID = 7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
declare @tbl table(TxnID int, RunningAmount int, MemberID int);
insert into @tbl values 
(1, 80000, 20),
(2, 90000, 20),
(3, 70000, 20),
(4, 90000, 20),
(5, 110000, 20),
(6, 60000, 20),
(7, 120000, 20),
(8, 85000, 28);

select TxnID, RunningAmount, MemberID,
       LAG(VShape) over (partition by MemberID order by TxnID) VShape
from (
    select TxnID, RunningAmount, MemberID,
           case when rn < lagrn and rn < leadrn then 1 else 0 end VShape
    from (
        select *,
               LAG(rn) over (partition by MemberID order by TxnID) lagRn,
               LEAD(rn) over (partition by MemberID order by TxnID) leadRn
        from (
            select TxnID,
                   RunningAmount,
                   MemberID,
                   ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by MemberID order by RunningAmount) rn
            from @tbl
        ) a
    ) a
) a
```

Last column `VShape` indicates if value in `RunningAmount` completes V shape (although you could be more clearer on what it means instead of everybody figuring it out). Now you can filter values based on `RunningAmount` (wheter they fall below or above 100k).

Here is version for earlier versions of SQL Server that don't have `LAG` and     `LEAD` functions:

```
;with cte as (
    select *,
           ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by MemberID order by RunningAmount) rn 
    from @tbl
), cte2 as (
    select c1.TxnID, c1.RunningAmount, c1.MemberID, c1.rn, c2.rn [lagRn] , c3.rn [leadRn]
    from cte c1 
    left join cte c2 on c1.TxnID = c2.TxnID + 1 and c1.MemberID = c2.MemberID
    left join cte c3 on c1.TxnID = c3.TxnID - 1 and c1.MemberID = c3.MemberID
), cte3 as (
    select TxnID, RunningAmount, MemberID,
           case when rn < lagrn and rn < leadrn then 1 else 0 end VShape
    from cte2
), FinalResult as (
    select c1.TxnID, c1.RunningAmount, c1.MemberID, c2.VShape
    from cte3 c1 
    left join cte3 c2 on c1.TxnID = c2.TxnID + 1 and c1.MemberID = c2.MemberID
)

select fr.*, fr2.RunningAmount RunningAmountLagBy2 from FinalResult fr
left join FinalResult fr2 on fr.TxnID = fr2.TxnID + 2
where fr.RunningAmount > 100000 and fr2.RunningAmount > 100000 and fr.VShape = 1
```

**UPDATE**

After question update, here's solution:

```
select TxnID from (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by VShape order by TxnID) CompletesVShape from (
        select TxnID,
               RunningAmount,
               MemberID,
               sum(case when RunningAmount >= 100000 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by MemberID order by TxnID rows between unbounded preceding and     current row) VShape
        from @tbl
    ) a
) a where VShape > 1 and CompletesVShape = 1
```

Comment: No lag nor lead on sql server 2008.

Comment: @EzLo Updated answer :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: Sorry for the lack of explanation earlier. I've edited my question and wish you can take some time to make sure we have the same understanding. Many thanks

Comment: @Isaac I understand your problem. Does my query solve it? If not, what's wrong? If so, you can accept the answer :)

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: Very close. But VShape on `ID=4` should not be 1 because the transactions before `ID=4` never exceeded 100k

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: `c2.TxnID + 1` cannot work on my updated data sample in my question. I need to skip ID7 and grab ID8 because ID8 is the one that exceeded 100k

Comment: @MichałTurczyn: Wow so much new keywords, will definitely try to digest them. Really appreciate very much on your help

Comment: @Isaac Note that first answer is for newer version than SQL Server 2008 (the one you tagged in a question). But you can learn it in some SQL fiddle online :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question update and assuming for V shape necessary condition is to get above and below running amounts > 100000 and middle be smaller than above and below running amounts, below is a query showing how to do it in 2008 sql server.

also see <kbd>**[live demo](http://rextester.com/MAT59489)**</kbd>

```
   ; with firstlargeamount as
(
    select MemberId, minTrxid=min(TxnID)
    from t  
    where RunningAmount>100000
    group by MemberId

)
,tbl as
( 
    select *,
    rn=row_number() over( partition by MemberId order by TxnId)
    from 
    t
)

select t3.*,f.* 
from tbl t1 
join tbl t2
    on 
        t1.memberId=t2.memberid and t1.rn=t2.rn +1
        and t1.RunningAmount<t2.RunningAmount
join tbl t3
    on 
        t1.memberId=t3.memberid and t1.rn=t3.rn -1
        and t1.RunningAmount<t3.RunningAmount
join firstlargeamount f
   on 
       f.Memberid=t2.memberid and f.minTrxid>=t1.TxnID
```

**Explanation:**

First step is to generate a row number sequence at member level as cte tbl and min limiting transaction in cte firstlargeamount

Second step is double self join to find above and below records per row which satisfy the V shape criteria as well join with firstlargeamount to find rows which satisfy the 100000 criteria
Note that the above and below records are simply found using +1/-1 from the current records's row number computed in the step 1

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation earlier. I've edited my question and wish you can take some time to make sure we have the same understanding. Many thanks